# Separated traffic for liveness\readiness prob

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

### Background

My application is hosted on Kubernetes. My pod contains nginx server that exposes my application to the internet.

```
customer <-> nginx <-> my-app
```

My deployment settings define a liveness\readiness policy that query my application every 30 seconds. If the application fails to answer for N times, the pod is going to be restarted.

### The Problem

Few times in a day I have peaks on traffic. This leads to one of the following two possibilities:

- The nginx server has a queue of request to respond to. After the nginx queue is full, the server is starting to immediately respond with 5xx for every response.
- The request has found a free spot on the queue, but the time to respond is longer than 30 seconds. The other side, the Kubernetes, stops waiting after this amount of time and count it as a failure.

As you see, in both case the Kubernetes will terminate my pod because off last of response from the liveness\readiness prob.

### Possible solutions

I had idea to separate the traffic coming from the nginx into two queues of request. One queue for the health checks and other queue for all the other requests. But I was couldn't find a way to implement it with nginx.

How do you recommend to solve the problem?

Comment: It sounds like the problem you should be solving is why your ingress controller is reaching a capacity limit